Azure Data Factory (ADF) Failed starting trigger after 5 attempts
Currently, we have enabled git management and disabled the publishing option via ADF.
We are only allowed to publish using the SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools.PublishADF.PublishADFTask@2
When I perform the publish step using my branch where I created a new trigger (BlobEventsTrigger) (everything seems to work just fine when I manually trigger the pipeline), I see the below error messages:
===================================================================================
STEP: Starting triggers...
TriggerStartMethod = BasedOnSourceCode
The number of triggers to start: 1
Starting triggers:
- Enabling trigger: my_trigger
Failed starting trigger after 5 attempts.
##[warning]HTTP Status Code: BadRequest
Error Code: BadRequest
Error Message: Entity my_trigger not found
Request Id: xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx
Timestamp (Utc):08/22/2024 14:21:57
Complete starting triggers.
==============================================================================

I dont understand why says that my_trigger is not found while it actually it uses the updated name that I gave to it

Problem was that the trigger objects were not part of the deployment object in the SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools.PublishADF.PublishADFTask@2 of our pipeline.
I had to adjust it like that:
          - task: SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools.PublishADF.PublishADFTask@2
            displayName: 'blablabla'
            inputs:
              .
              .
              .
              FilterText: |
                +pipeline.*
                +linkedService.*
                +dataset.*
                +trigger.*  <- This was missing

Documentaion
